# Triangle with height linked to data in R

Tags: r, visualization

My Dataset

[image]

My Requirement

[image]

Basically, I need a simple triangle chart where the height is the value in No column and Group Name in box. The width can be of any size. If we can have different colors for different sets it will be great.

I am new to R, and have tried `polygon`, `lapply`, `geom_polygon`, `triangle`, `pascal triangle`, `ade4`, `pyramid` and others, but no success.

Also, in R Studio this should be as a plot visual not in viewer visual.

Comment: Scaling the height instead of the area is really dishonest visualization.

Comment: @MarkLakata I'm still trying to convince my boss about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not find a good package for this, but I was able to make the plot.  Sorry, I don't use R Studio, so I'm not sure what your last point means.

```
plot.pyramid <- function(df, hspace=2, colours=NA){

    n <- nrow(df) #number of observations

    #i don't know what you want to do with colors
    if(any(is.na(colours))) colours <- rep('blue', n) 
    if(length(colours)<n) colours <- rep(colours,n)[1:n]

    cum.height <- cumsum(df$no) #cumulative height. y coordinates in plot

    max.cum.height <- max(cum.height) #max height of the graph

    center <- max(cum.height)/2 #where to center the x values

    #there are 2 y values per point to make the horizontal segments
    y <- max.cum.height - rep(cum.height,2) 
    x <- c(center-cum.height/2, center + cum.height/2) #horizontal segments are same size as height, centered

    x <- c(x, center) #add x-coord for tip
    y <- c(y, max.cum.height) #add y-coord for tip

    reorder <- order(y) #reorder points for convenience in 'for loop' below

    y <- y[reorder]
    x <- x[reorder]

    plot(x,y,'n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann = FALSE) #creates blank plot of correct size

    for(i in 0:(n-1) ){

        if(i != n-1) #if not tip
        {
            xcoords <- x[i*2+1:4][c(1,3,4,2)] #reorder the points slightly to get a trapezoid fill
            ycoords <- y[i*2+1:4][c(1,3,4,2)]
            #add the space between the trapezoids
            ycoords[ycoords==min(ycoords)] <- ycoords[ycoords==min(ycoords)] + hspace
        }else{
            xcoords <- x[i*2+1:3] #triangle only has 3 points
            ycoords <- y[i*2+1:3]
            ycoords <- ycoords + hspace
        }

        polygon(xcoords,ycoords,col=colours[i+1])  #plot points and fill
        text(mean(xcoords), mean(ycoords), cex=.8, paste(df$group[n-i], df$no[n-i]) ) #add text
    }

}

df <- data.frame(group=c(paste0('Group-',seq(5))), no=c(5,25,36,40,50))
colours <- c('blue','green','blue','gray','green')
plot.pyramid(df, 2, colours)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `ggplot2`

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt.triangle <- data.table(group = c(1,1,1), polygon.x = c(2,4,3), polygon.y = c(1,1,3))

ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = dt.triangle,
               aes( x=polygon.x,y=polygon.y,group=group), fill="#3182bd") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.24, y = 1.5, xend = 3.78, yend = 1.5), 
               size=2, color="white") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.49, y = 2, xend = 3.52, yend = 2), 
               size=2, color="white") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.74, y = 2.5, xend = 3.26, yend = 2.5), 
               size=2, color="white") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.865, y = 2.75, xend = 3.134, yend = 2.75), 
               size=2, color="white") +
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 1.25, label = "Group-5 50", size=3) +
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 1.75, label = "Group-4 40", size=3) +
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 2.25, label = "Group-3 36", size=3) +
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 2.65, label = "Group-2 25", size=3) +
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 2.85, label = "Group-1 5", size=3) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank())
```

[image]